# How to change UID,GID of user accounts while migrating from one server to another Centos 7 server

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, centos7, user-accounts

I have a mail server running with 1000 users. I want to migrate the server to Centos 7 server.

Scenario 1 (Old server): user accounts UID start with 501

Scenario 2 (New Centos 7 Server) : user account start with 1001 that is defined in /etc/login.defs

So i can not migrate the user account to my new server. Because of the UID mismatch issue.

How can i migrate the previous servers users to my new Centos 7 server that UID start with 1001 ???

Comment: Why can you not migrate the users? Why do you need to change their UIDs?

Comment: Because in my new server SYSID is up to 999. and already has some system users accounts between 501 to 999. So i can not migrate the previous users that is between 501 to 999. i can migrate the users whose UID is 1000+ . But i am facing the issue for UID 501 to 999. IS there any workaround?

Comment: You can renumber all those users, but it's a manual process. I know of no automation to help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

Where an external directory exists, use that for users. For LDAP or Active Directory on modern Linux, sssd is a common choice.

When you still want to use files, copy the entire files from old server to new: `/etc/passwd /etc/shadow /etc/group`.  Warnings:

- You can **lock yourself out** of access.
- You must use the old credentials.
- This won't work when moving between Linux or UNIX distribution families, they each have their own assumptions about UIDs and GIDs.

Or, you can still specify the user and group IDs, even below the default "system user" threshold. Definitely consider doing so if you care about what ID each gets.

```
[root@sf ~]# groupadd textgroup --gid 501
[root@sf ~]# useradd person --gid 501 --uid 501
[root@sf ~]# id person
uid=501(person) gid=501(textgroup) groups=501(textgroup)
[root@sf ~]# grep PRETTY /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. In my new Centos 7 server some system user id already exists there between 501 and 999. So I can not migrate the old servers users that reside between 501 to 999. I am afraid to change UID and GID limit under /etc/login.defs. In this case is there any workarond???

Comment: Then you need to (manually) merge the IDs and change some. I would install a very minimal OS, copy `/etc/passwd`, install additional software, and fix up UIDs, in that order.   A UID can be changed, but they need to be logged out after, and  you will have lingering issues with the old UID, like file permissions.